# Generic construction of a probability measure on a random variable X

Tags: probability-theory

Let's consider the usual setting for a probability space, that is:
$X:(\Omega,\mathscr{B}) \longrightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})) $ . Where X is a random variable; now consider a probability measure on X as:

$P \circ X^{-1}(-\infty,x]=P[X\leq x]$

Given that for A $\subset \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$,  $X^{-1}(A)=${$\omega:X(\omega) \in A$}
Now, might someone explain me the passage from $P \circ X^{-1}(-\infty,x]$ to $P[X\leq x]$? Actually I do not understand how I can substitute the interval with the "$\leq$" sign (which is indeed the usual expression for a probability distribution function). The book to which I refer is Resnick, 'Probability Path' chapter 3.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X^{-1}(-\infty,x]=\{\omega \in \Omega: X (\omega) \leq x\}$. The notation $[X \leq x]$ is used in Probability theory as  an abbreviation for $\{\omega \in \Omega: X (\omega) \leq x\}$.